# EC2 Failed Health Check

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, volumes

I have an EC2 instance lets call it A that is failing one health check at time of boot and causing the instacne unreachable or inaccessible. System logs shows "Out of Storage".

I hvae done following:

- Attached the root volume to different instance to expand its size.
- Mounted the disk as root volume on a new EC2 B by removing its root and it worked fine and 35GB was availabel.
- Mounted the vol of new instance B on instance A that is failing as root and it also worked fine.
- Took AMI which also accessible.

It seem issue is with some process that is causing this.

Comment: Can you just use Option #2 (mounting disk on instance B)?

Comment: We need to find RCA and recovery also for the failed instance